# DCOS Mesos agent fails to retrieve private resources from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, dcos

I'm trying to deploy applications on a DC/OS stack in AWS, via universe packages. As I understand it, mesos fetcher will attempt to retrieve these resources and containerize them as defined in the marathon.json. These resources are private, and need to remain private. They are not static so using a pre-signed url is most likely out of the question.

I've defined the resources in a package. When the Agents try to resolve the resources they receive a 403.

Defining the uri as http://s3domain/bucket/key or https:// returns the 403.
defining the uri as s3:// the mesos fetcher calls hadoop (which we otherwise do not need)

The trying to pull the resources with the AWS CLI from the agent nodes works. Mesos fetcher will also succeed for any public resources.

I've seen some solutions that use nginx to proxy s3 and embed aws credentials in the request. The only other solution I've see is to containerize everything before hand and setup s3 as a Docker registry. Are these the only ways to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer, but might help for someone else in future.

You can follow below steps to access private s3 buckets from mesos/dcos cluster.

- [Create](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-vpc-endpoint/) a VPC endpoint for the VPC of DCOS/mesos.
- Use that endpoint in bucket [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html) for private s3 bucket.
- For test, try to access the s3 resource using curl from mesos node, if works , then you are good to go.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html